# Adjusting \underbrace "cursor" at horizontal axis

Tags: horizontal-alignment, braces

Given is following formula:

```
\[
\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{k=-n}^k c_ke^{ikx}=\frac{a_0}{2}+&\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(c_ke^{ikx}+c_{-k}e^{-ikx}\right)}\\
&=\cos(kx)(c_n+c_{-n})+i\sin(kx)(c_k-c_{-k})\\
&=a_k\cos(kx)+b_k\sin(kx)
\end{split}
\]
```

[image: rendered math formula]

The underbrace-command points to the next line, but it should point to the equal sign at the beginning of this line. Is it possible to either move the "cursor" of the underbrace-command to the equal sign or to move the equal sign to the underbrace-"cursor"?

Comment: Should the underbrace cover the summation sign, or only the expression in round parentheses?

Comment: @Mico: This does not make any difference. Sometimes I need such a feature, therefore it should work with any content.

Comment: please put an empty group `{}` between the plus and the ampersand before the second sum; this is needed to get the correct spacing around the plus.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thank you for the tip. I notice the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

I've used `\mathrlap` from the `mathtools` package, which loads (and extends) the `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{k=-n}^k c_ke^{ikx}=\frac{a_0}{2}+
&\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(c_ke^{ikx}+c_{-k}e^{-ikx}\right)}
                                _{\mathrlap{\begin{array}{@{}l}
                                =\cos(kx)(c_n+c_{-n})+i\sin(kx)(c_k-c_{-k})\\
                                =a_k\cos(kx)+b_k\sin(kx)\end{array}}}\\
\end{split}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Haha! Neat trick.

Comment: I'm not totally satisfied with this solution, because the "cursor" of the brace does not exactly point to the equal sign.

Comment: @Antoras so do you want to move it to the left a bit? you could try shifting it left a bit using a negative `hspace`

Comment: Ok, this is not the perfect solution because of hand-adjusting but it works.